# What are the best practices for managing huge schema using express-graphql

Tags: express-graphql

I'm seeking advice. My schema.js file is reaching 1000 lines and I'm only halfway. What would be a decent file structure to spill schema.js onto?

Comment: Take a look at this, it is basically splitting the modules into separate files and importing them all into schema.js before exporting the schema for use. https://www.apollographql.com/blog/backend/schema-design/modularizing-your-graphql-schema-code/

Comment: @aside, thank you! The problem is I have all the `schema.js` written in JavaScript, not in Apollo notation in backticks. Refactoring would take a lot of work.